# Slow realtime matplotlib color matrix plotting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, raspberry-pi

I am trying to plot a real time pcolor map using matplotlib.

I am trying to plot in real time but it is really slow (i am using raspberry pi and python)

this program simply needs to change all the 0s to 1s but it takes very long.
How can I speed it up?

this is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

plot.ion()
vector = np.zeros((20,1))
i=0

while i<10:
   vector[i] = 1
   plot.pcolor(vector)
   plot.draw()
   plot.pause(0.0001)
   i = i+1
```

Comment: very short (and some what useless answer) is use blitting.  You might also want to use `imshow` instead of `pcolor`.  Also, importing pyplot as `plot` is unconventional and shadows the `plot` function.  The convention is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Comment: thank you very much, I changed to imshow and plt, could you give me a small example how to use blitting?